# Math mode horizontal space difference between \ (backslash) and \; (backslash semicolon) and what to use for multiplication

Tags: math-mode, spacing, best-practices

In this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
c = a b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I would like to insert a space between 'a' and 'b' (as opposed to `\cdot` or `\times`). Usually, I just write a simple backslash:

```
c = a \ b
```

This seems to produce the same spacing as:

```
c = a \; b
```

Is there a difference? What kind of spacing do you recommend to use for multiplication: `\` (backslash) or `\,` (backslash comma) or `\:` (backslash colon) or `\;` (backslash semicolon) or some other spacing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The recommended space for a multiplication is *no space*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use *no space* between terms that are multiplied. So

```
$c=ab$
```

is the correct way of typing the formula. In case you have

```
$c=a\log b$
```

TeX takes care of the spacing and automatically inserts a thin space (equivalent to `\,`): you have to do nothing at all except using the right command (`\log` for the logarithm).

Note that spaces in math formulas are ignored, so

```
$c = a b$
```

produces the same result as $c=ab$.

About the differences among the various commands:

1. `\` (backslash space) inserts a normal interword space; use it for separating terms in an equation, but in general it shouldn't be used in math
2. `\,` inserts a thin space, the same that's automatically inserted in `$a\log b$` both after `a` and `\log`
3. `\:` is the same spacing that's automatically inserted around the `+` sign in `$a+b$` (or, in general, around binary operation symbols)
4. `\;` is the same spacing that's automatically inserted around the `=` sign in `$a=b$` (or, in general, around binary relation symbols)

In some cases it's good to add an explicit spacing, for instance in

```
$\sqrt{\,\log x}$
```

because of the high ell that goes in the corner of the radical. But such manual adjustments are rarely needed.

Comment: Thanks. I realize my question is not good. The context is that I have an equation like $c = f(a) f(b)$ where f is a function. If I use amsmath and the command \DeclareMathOperator{\f}{f}, then there's a space between f(a) and f(b) and f is not in italics, otherwise f is in italics and there is no space between f(a) and f(b). What's the best practice for this case ?

Comment: @needsaname `$f(a)f(b)$` is what's always done. Use `\DeclareMathOperator` only for functions that have a “proper name” like logarithm, sine, cosine and similar, not for “generic” functions, whose name is just a variable like ”x” or ”y” for numbers.

Comment: @greg so is it an inconsistency that the spacing in `$f(a)f(b)$` is different than the spacing in `$\log(a)\log(b)$`, just because `$f$` is a function with a one letter name whereas `$\log$` is a function with a 3 letter name ?

Comment: @needsaname The thin space before `\cos` in `$\sin a \cos b$` (I usually avoids parentheses in these cases) is precisely for making it clear that we're using an operator name, rather than variables to be multiplied.